# InkCanvas styluspoint timestamp

Tags: c#, wpf, timestamp, inkcanvas

in the Microsoft.Ink world for WinForms, using an InkCollector object, a user could get the timestamp of a point in a stroke via [this approach](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tabletandtouch/thread/2e6da33c-488b-470e-a0bb-ccf45dad2bbc).  The WPF world relies instead on the InkCanvas object, and while it has many properties, I can't seem to find a Tick or Timestamp for StylusPoints collected in the strokes.  Is there an equivilant way to do this in the WPF InkCanvas?

it looks like I can intercept the strokes [like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749105%28VS.85%29.aspx), but the StylusPoint is a sealed struct, so I can't just inherit/add a new property.

Answer (score 0):

From the link you showed, the parameter to the functions is RawStylusInput - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.stylusplugins.rawstylusinput.aspx - which has a Timestamp property.

So, it seems you don't have access to a timestamp per point, but for each event.  I suspect that's all the resolution available from WinForms anyway.